# Material Text fields without labels

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

In material.io there is a section about `Text fields without labels`, it will become like this
[image]

When edittext location is focus, the label focus too. How to achieve that? because i tried by using separate textview, but when edittext is focus, the label is not focus too

```
    <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_16"
        android:text="Testing Label" />

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/outlinedTextField"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.Dense"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Won't the xml attribute 'android:labelFor' on the TextView work as well?

Comment: i tried to add `android:labelFor`, but still the text color didnt change to focus color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
outlinedTextInputLayout.getEditText().setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus)
            label.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.xxxx));
        else
            label.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.xxxx));
    }
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set a focus change listener on your `TextInputEditText` and change the label color accordingly.

```
editText.setOnFocusChangeListener { v, hasFocus ->
    if (hasFocus)
        label.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary))
    else
        label.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.defaultColor))
}
```

Comment: yes it is working, but any other solution for that if i have many edittext?

Comment: You'll have to set different focus change listeners for different `EditText`s, and implement this in all of them.